# Trigonometry: Tan Numerator Divide by Tan Denom

Tags: calculus

I am confused about how to approach this problem:

[image]

I looked at cheat sheets online and the closest I could find was this:  But it is not quite what I'm looking for.

[image]

A step by step guide would be helpful.

Comment: What problem? Do you want to simplify this expression?

Comment: I want to solve (or get the top problem most simplified)

Comment: 75=45+30. Use trig formulae for sum of angles.

Comment: Here's a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint, you can reduce to: $$\frac{1-\frac{\tan(45)+\tan(30)}{1-\tan(30)\tan(45)}}{1+\frac{\tan(45)+\tan(30)}{1-\tan(30)\tan(45)}}$$

Answer (score 3):

The formula I'd use here is
\begin{equation*}
 \tan(\alpha - \beta) \equiv \frac{\tan \alpha - \tan \beta}{1 + \tan \alpha \tan \beta}
\end{equation*}
so by letting $\alpha = 45^\circ$ (which will make $\tan \alpha$ be $1$) and $\beta = 75^\circ$, your fraction just becomes $\tan(45^\circ - 75^\circ) = \tan(-30^\circ) = -\frac{\sqrt 3}3$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\tan (\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta}{1-\tan \alpha \tan \beta}$$

and $75°=45°+30°$

Comment: any additional hints ... or perhaps a sample problem I can look at for context?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using this formula:

$$\tan (\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan \alpha+\tan \beta}{1-\tan \alpha \tan \beta}$$

$$\tan 75° = \tan (45°+30°)=\frac{\tan 45°+\tan 30°}{1-\tan 45° \tan 30°}$$

The two expressions involving the tangent are easy to calculate:

$$\tan 45° = 1$$
$$\tan 30° = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

If you plug those in, you will get the value for $\tan{75°}$.

Once you got the value for $\tan 75°$, put it into your original equation.